# If a function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is continuous at $0$, then it is continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. If $f$ is continuous at zero how can I prove that is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By sliding around a neighborhood of zero. In other words if $\delta$ is very close to zero, then by continuity, so is $f(\delta)$, and so is $f(x + \delta) = f(x) + f(\delta)$. Now just formalize that argument.

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/proving-that-an-additive-function-f-is-continuous-if-it-is-continuous-at-a-sin (And as was already pointed out, you can find more related posts here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation)

Answer (score 2):

1. Show $f(0)=0$
2. For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|f(x+h)-f(x)|=|f(h)|$

Answer (score 1):

Prove it is Lipschitz. (Actually you can prove it is of the form $f(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$.) See also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the definition, prove that $f(0)=0$ and use 
$$f(a+\varepsilon)-f(a)=f(\varepsilon)\,.$$