# Continuity of additive functions

Tags: functions, continuity, additive-categories

I was checking this link [Proving that an additive function $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at a single point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/proving-that-an-additive-function-f-is-continuous-if-it-is-continuous-at-a-sin) and both Jspecter and Alex Becker's solutions seem to rely on the fact that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x-a+c)$$
Could someone please explain to me how is that you can change the scalar that x is approaching and still hold the equality? And how can you tell that $$f(x-a+c)$$ is defined?
I'm sorry I didn't ask this question in the original post but I don't have the right to comment right now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just substituting the variables - instead of $x\to c$ take $x=y-a+c$, or $y=x+a-c$. Then $y\to a$, and we get that
$$\lim_{x\to c}f\left(x\right)=\lim_{x\to c}f\left(x+a-c-a+c\right)=\lim_{y\to a}f\left(y-a+c\right)$$
But instead of renaming the variable as $y$, they kept denoting it $x$.

Comment: Thanks, from what I understand from your answer is that because we know that $$f(a)$$ is defined, then they're adding and subtracting the same term right? But where does the c come from on the right hand side of $$x=y-a+c$$? I know that x was approaching c originally, but isn't adding that c assume that f(c) is defined, which is precisely what we're trying to prove?

Comment: We are trying to prove that assuming $f\left(c\right)$ exists, then
$$\lim_{x\to c}f\left(x\right)=f\left(c\right)$$
If $f\left(c\right)$ is not defined, the question whether the function is continuous at $c$ is meaningless