# Continuity limits

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

from a previous question asked here [Proving that an additive function $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at a single point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/proving-that-an-additive-function-f-is-continuous-if-it-is-continuous-at-a-sin) someone stated that the key step is that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a}f(x-a+c)$ however I don't understand how that is true shouldn't $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a}f(x+a-c)$ ?
Thanks for you help!

Comment: First equation is correct and you can convince yourself by putting $t=x-a+c$ so that when $x\to a$ we have $t\to c$.

Comment: why is the first equation correct though, what is the rationale to getting up to that point?

Comment: Did you try the substitution $t=x-a+c$? It is obvious once you try this.

Comment: if $f(x-a+c)$ approaches a then |(x-a+c)-a| by the definition of a limit which does not equal |x-c|

Comment: $t=x-a+c$ approaches $c$ (and not $a$ as you think) when $x\to a$ and vice versa. Perhaps you are trying to think too deeply about trivial issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is confusing you is the re-use of the variable $x$.

In fact, this $x$ is a dummy variable.

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{y\to c}f(y)$ or $\lim\limits_{foo\to c}f(foo)$ are exactly the same thing, right ?

Now let's rewrite the correct statement using different dummy variables:

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim\limits_{y\to a}f(y-a+c)$

Intuititvely $x\to c$ means $x=c+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is a very small quantity.

Yet $(y-a)$ is also such a very small quantity.

Thus in the substitution $x=c+\overbrace{(y-a)}^{\varepsilon}$ then $y\to a\iff x\to c$

The confusion arised because the dummy variable $y$ was changed back to $x$ leading to:

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x-a+c)$

but you should really see it as a substitution like I explained before.

Comment: sorry I'm just having trouble understanding this part y→a⟺x→c

Comment: it just means that if $y$ get very close to $a$ then $(y-a)$ is very close to $0$ so $x$ is very close to $c$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)$ can this concept also be used? to just replace h with y-a?

Comment: This would be $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(c+h)$ but yes, just replace $h$ with $y-a$ and you get the result.