# Cauchy functional equation - Proving $f(x) = mx$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ if $f$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) $

I proved if $f$ is continuous at $0$ then it is continuous on $\mathbb R$
And also I proved the $f(nx) = nf(x)$ identity for rationals and integers as well.

it seems obvious $f(x) = mx$ but how do I approach from the continuity?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I read that post but couldn't find the particular solution

Comment: @Lufifer I think you haven't read carefully. A solution of cauchy functional equation is continuous if it is continuous at a single point. $\\$ Every continuous solution of cauchy functional equation is of the form $f(x) =mx$

Comment: @SouravGhosh THANK you. I think I proved it. I took a rational number sequence which converges to a real number and used the sequential criteria to verify the solution, $=mx$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93816/977780 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/356645/977780

Comment: @SouravGhosh thank you I did the same!